# Two different pictographs of the same animal species plus another – most portable way to achieve this?

Tags: unicode

#### Actual Question

I want to represent something like the following in Unicode:

[image: example of the desired result]

More specifically, I am looking for a set of Unicode representations (character or character plus modifiers) comprising of:

1. Any life form that is not a humanoid. I prefer animals, but plants, fungi, etc. are also okay.
2. A different representation of the same species. The distinction could be something like point of view, mood, or colour. I prefer the colours, ideally unrealistic ones, say a green and a pink elephant. Different sexes or ages of the same species (e.g., rooster, hen, and chick) do not work.
3. A different non-human life form that is otherwise comparable (point of view, etc.). Ideally it lives in the same habitat as the other one; so no mountain goats and deep-sea fish.

The representations of each must be separate. For example, one character featuring two cats does not work for me. It should not be necessary to guess that the characters represent animals; so ∀ representing an ox doesn’t work.

Here is the catch: I am looking for the **most portable** solution, i.e., one that works on as many devices as possible. If you need something quantifiable, go by the Unicode version.

#### What I found so far

- I could use a smiling cat face, an pouting cat face, and some other animal face:  (U+1F638, U+1F63E, U+1F437). These are in Unicode since Version 6.0. and thus is not very portable: The cat faces look different than the pig face depending on where I view those characters.
- I could use the black and white chess knight: ♞♘ (U+2658, U+265E). These are in Unicode since version 1.1 and hence very portable. However, I am lacking the third pictograph, since the other chess pieces are not non-human animals.

#### Why on earth do I want this?

I am about to submit a manuscript on ecological modelling to an academic journal. This journal asks for a “tweetable abstract”, which is strongly character-limited. The requested symbols would allow me to illustrate the key scenario considered in my manuscript very concisely.

Comment: The full list of animal is at [Unicode Emojis: Full list of animals — Burst SMS](https://blog.burstsms.com.au/sms-marketing/2017/5/24/unicode-emoji-list-aniamls). There are some new ones as well added in 2019 [New animal emojis approved for 2019 update - Discover Wildlife](https://www.discoverwildlife.com/news/animal-wildlife-emojis-2019/)

Comment: In the first list are the 3 wise monkeys, 2 camels (1 hump and 2 hump), rooster (male)/chicken (female), whale/whale (squirting), fish/tropical fish, dog/poodle, ram (male)/sheep,

Comment: @DavidPostill: Thanks, that’s a helpful overview. Dromedaries and camels are two different species. Different sexes are not such a good choice (due to complicated reasons). The ignorant monkeys and the whale squirtiness might be an option to consider.

Comment: There is also Dragon (U+1f409) and Dragon Face (U+1f432) for the first two. A comparable but different species could be Snake (U+1f40d).

Comment: I don't know if White Chess Knight, Black Chess Knight and Star (U+2605) for starfish could work?

Comment: If a combination is OK you could also do a snake like this: ⎯⎯⎯O< (U+23af x3, U+4f, U+3c)

Comment: @PieBie: Please note the criterion: “It should not be necessary to guess that the characters represent animals”. Thus, no ASCII art.